# Build for Ionic project hangs in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

Im using Visual Studio 2017 and starter menu template from Ionic. When i try to build the project (to deploy it to device or run in simulator for example) build process hangs. The green bar for build just keeps scrolling but nothing happens. Task Runner Explorer window shows that ionic-app-scripts build task finished.
Im running Visual Studio as Administrator on high end workstation, so im not quite sure what can be the problem. I also deleted all files from temp folder regarding visual studio, but that did not help.
I tried building for android and windows configurations.
[image]

Has anyone else ever experienced this kind of problem, or have any guides on what to try on next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It seems that ionic build task does not notify properly VS that it is finished, so VS build is waiting for it forever. I excluded that ionic build task from build process and run it manually before VS Build and everything works ok now.